# Enable Scrolling using up and down arrow key through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hotkeys

I am trying to enable scrolling using the down arrow and up arrow key on my website. This is the script I have been trying yo use, however, the scrolling is still disabled

Can someone please help me understand if I am headed in the right direction?

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/hotkeys-js/dist/hotkeys.min.js"></script>
<script type="module">
  import hotkeys from '/hotkeys-js';
  hotkeys('ctrl+a,alt+a+s', {
    keyup: true
  }, function(event, handler) {
    if (event.type === 'keydown') {
      console.log('keydown:', event.type, handler, handler.key);
    }

    if (event.type === 'keyup') {
      console.log('keyup:', event.type, handler, handler.key);
    }
  });
</script>

<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Scroll</p>
<p>Down</p>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It gives a [very clear error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=cannot+use+import+outside+module+browser+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I fixed the error by changing type="text/javascript" to type="module", added the `/` to the import and added some Ps. It still does not work though